# How to create my own columns with DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = False

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Using Windows Forms. Following example from [DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns?view=netframework-4.7.2). I'm trying to figure out how to add custom columns with AutoGenerateColumns = False.

```
Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    SetBinding3()
End Sub 

Private Class Employee
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _Name As String
End Class

Private employees As New List(Of Employee)
Dim bs As New BindingSource
Private Sub SetBinding3()
    employees.Add(New Employee With {.Name = "Henry"})
    employees.Add(New Employee With {.Name = "Mary"})

    dgBilling.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    bs.DataSource = employees
    dgBilling.DataSource = bs

    Dim col2 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    col2.HeaderText = "Name"
    col2.Name = "Name"
    col2.ValueType = GetType(String)
    col2.DataPropertyName = "Name"
    col2.Width = 500
    col2.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black
    col2.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige
    dgBilling.Columns.Add(col2)

    dgBilling.Refresh()
End Sub
```

It all seems to work fine except I don't see the data in the DataGridView. If I click on it the names become selected and visible. But if I don't select then it's not visible. I tried setting the ForeColor and BackColor to no avail. How do I properly add a column with AutoGenerateColumns = False?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had an error in the RowPrePaint handler. It was referencing a column that didn't exist. As a result of the error the rows were not being rendered.

```
Private Sub dgv_RowPrePaint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles dgv.RowPrePaint
    dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("RowColor").Value
End Sub
```

Once I fixed the error, everything showed fine!

Answer (score 1):

There's probably an easier way, but I've had success with this. Note that I have custom classes being bound to the DataGridView with List(Of T) and not a BindingSource. The string `columns` is a pairing of the object's property name and the column's header text. i.e. "Name" is `Product.Name` and "Product #" is what is shown in the DataGridView column header.

```
    dgvItemList.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    dgvItemList.DataSource = Services.MasterLists.Products.GetList

    Dim columns As String() = {"ID", "ID",
                               "Name", "Product #",
                               "Description", "Description",
                               "Family", "Family",
                               "Comments", "Comments"}

    Helpers.Controls.AddColumnsToDataGridView(dgvItemList, columns)

    dgvItemList.Columns(0).Visible = False
    dgvItemList.Columns(1).Width = 90
    dgvItemList.Columns(2).Width = 200
    dgvItemList.Columns(3).Width = 100
    dgvItemList.Columns(4).Width = 200
```

And the definition of Helpers.Controls.AddColumnsToDataGridView:

```
Public Shared Sub AddColumnsToDataGridView(ByRef dgv As DataGridView, ByVal columns As String())

    dgv.Columns.Clear()
    For i As Integer = 0 To columns.Length - 1 Step 2

        Dim column As DataGridViewColumn = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()

        ' i = index of the object's property name. i + 1 = the column name to show in the grid
        column.DataPropertyName = columns(i)
        column.Name = columns(i + 1)
        dgv.Columns.Add(column)

    Next

End Sub
```

The reason I do it this way is because I don't want the DataGridView to show all Properties of the `Product` object, just the fields I want shown.